# Monitor displays error msg after I turn on the CPU: " D-sub no signal "

Tags: motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card, desktop

My desktop was working fine a few hours ago. after I shifted it to a different room, it had started showing message " D-sub no signal " whenever I turn it on. Spent much time on Google trying to figure out the probable cause. Mostly what I came across were suggestions to try to  reinstall components of motherboard, say RAM/ Graphics card, processor.
I tried them all, but no luck. It was only after I turned on the PC after entirely removing the graphics card that the monitor seemed to work normally.

Does this mean my graphics card is corrupt? If it is, then I'm a bit confused as to what caused that as I took great care while shifting it.

Graphics card: nvidia GT 710 2gb
Motherboard: asus

Comment: Lot of stuff to guess at there... presumably you were using the D-sub port on your NVidia? or? What are you connecting with now that card's not in the machine?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I tried with the graphics card d-sub port. But I remember for sure that when the graphics card was in there I was using the motherboard's built in VGA port, not the graphics card's.

Comment: then it sounds like the BIOS is set to use the card, not the onboard video as primary. Only when that card is missing would it revert to onboard.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks a ton for that simple yet miraculous question. It's working now. I just installed the graphics card back in and plugged the cable into the d-sub of graphics card instead of that of the motherboard.

Comment: Let me throw some of that logic into something approaching an answer... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By process of elimination & assuming it is a configuration error rather than component failure...

...also assuming the monitor settings haven't been changed it is correct in expecting a VGA signal over the d-sub connection.

If the onboard video doesn't work until the PCI graphics card is removed, one possibility is that the BIOS has been told to use the PCI as its primary output. It would only revert to internal graphics if that card vanished.

Ergo - plugging the PCI card back in & the d-sub into the PCI graphics rather than onboard ought to fix it.